# x11vnc on embedded raspberry QT5 app

Tags: c++, qt5, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, vnc

I need to start a VNC server (x11vnc) in my Raspberry pi 3. It's running without X-server (Raspbian Lite). My app (C++ QT 5) writes directly to Linux framebuffer.

Following to some instructions in [Qt creator forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/66162/running-vnc-server-on-embedded-linux/2), I've done some progress.
At this moment I can start a x11vnc server, connect to Raspberry via a regular VNC client and use my app with mouse and keyboard.

YES, IT'S WORKING.

BUT... If I change the Raspberry resolution (raspi-config) to something different from 1280x720, I don't know why, I can't see the screen perfectly. The VNC client shows a distorted display, like the image bellow.

[image]

(And, unfortunately I can't set a fixed resolution)

This is my actual settings to start x11vnc:

```
x11vnc -permitfiletransfer -nopw -rawfb +/dev/fb0 -forever -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -xrandr -bg -shared -pipeinput UINPUT:accel=0.7,reset=0 -cursor none -nodragging
```

I already tried to start with `-clip 1280x720+0+0`, `-geometry 1280x720` and `-scale 1280x720`, (with other values too) but had the same problem. =/

And I start my application like this:

```
my-app -platform linuxfb
```

Both are started with root user.

If someone have an idea of how to fix this, please tell me know! Thanks!

Comment: I know this may have very little to do with your issue, but the issue looks similar to when raster images are misaligned, i.e. the image width is not evenly divisible by 4 (or 8).  Same staircase effect.  Maybe you should investigate this angle?

Comment: Not a good fit for Stack Overflow as this isn't a programming problem or a programming tool problem. Not sure what Stack Exchange site this does fit.